# Parse string into array when string is separated by a number of nulls

Tags: c#, string

I have a file that, after opening it in Notepad++ looks like it contains character strings separated by 3 null characters.
I tried:

```
using (StreamReader _sr = new StreamReader(FilePath)){
    string _stuff = _sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] _test = _stuff.Split(new char[]{(char) 0},3);
}
```

but `_test`, which is the result of the split shows the bulk of the string (including those separated by 3 nulls).

How can I turn this:

> AAA**NULNULNUL**BBB**NULNULNUL**CCCC**NULNULNUL**

into this:

> {"AAA","BBB","CCC"}

Comment: Why not just split the strings on `NULNULNUL` and then iterate through the array and remove the indexes that have the `NULNULNUL`, therefore leaving you with `AAA`, `BBB`, AND `CCCC`

Comment: Are you seeing the bulk of the string in the last member of `_test`?  Be aware that the `3` you're passing isn't saying "look for 3 null characters", it is instead saying "return at most 3 strings"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `String.Split`:

```
  String source = "AAA\0\0\0BBB\0\0\0CCCC\0\0\0";

  String[] result = source.Split(
    new Char[] { '\0' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Test:

```
   // AAA, BBB, CCCC
   Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```

In case you want to split by *tripled* NUL *only*:

```
  String[] result = source.Split(
    new String[] { "\0\0\0" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_stuff.Split("NUL").Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray()
```

This way you dont care for number of NUL repetitions.

Edit thanks to &fubo ->  `_stuff.Split("NUL", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()`

If by NULL was meant null char, you can use '\0'

Comment: By "NUL" the OP means NULL character (ASCII 0) not an string containing N, U and L.

Comment: i would use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead of filtering empty entries in another iteration

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing a string with control characters. `NUL` is 0<sup>th</sup> control character. You can use the following:

```
var _test = _stuff.Split(new []{(char) 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cleanArray = Regex.Replace(source, @"\0+", " ")
                          .Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Bit late to the party but this works fine to.